# windowClosing() and throwing exceptions

Tags: java, swing, exception, file-io, windowlistener

I'm trying to save information (a vector to a file) before the window (and script) is closed. I have check and search everywhere I can't find what to do.

The Error I'm having is

> unreported exception java.lang.exception; must be caught or declare to
>   be thrown  savePlayers().

However I'm using `loadPlayers` which do the opposite and I don't have any problem with Exceptions. Help anyone please? The code is:

```
static public void savePlayers() throws Exception
{
    //serialize the List    
        try 
        {
        FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME);
            ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
            output.writeObject(players);
            output.close();
        }  
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println (ex.toString());
        }
}



public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Teams");
    frame.setSize(700,500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
        {
            try
            {
                savePlayers();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                 ex.printStackTrace();              
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why are you using `System.exit(0)`? What do you think about `frame.dispose()`?

Comment: @Braj I also exit the application, so not sure if dispose do that

Comment: Read about `frame.dispose()` method.

Comment: If Frame.dispose() would perform the same, System.exit() is more understandable and allows controlling the exit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your these lines of code in `main` method

```
try
{
   savePlayers();
}
catch (IOException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();              
}
```

Change it to catch

```
try
{
   savePlayers();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();              
}
```

It will work. Your `savePlayers()` method throws `Exception` not `IOException`.

The above will fix the issue but I don't know why your savePlayers() method have this strange `throws Exception` in method definition? You should think to remove it, as your code not throwing any exception. If it is, handle it along with your `IOException`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the savePlayers method to:

```
static public void savePlayers()
```

Or, change the window listener action to:

```
@Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
    {
        try
        {
            savePlayers();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();              
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

The first option is better because you actually do not need to throw Exception in the savePlayers()

Comment: Thank you @suhe_arie but I went to the second option and I'll check the first one when I have more time.